# How to monitor local documents directory NSMetaDataQuery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

With iCloud, I set up a MetaDataQuery like so:

```
[query setSearchScopes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];
```

How do I set up the same MetaDataQuery for my normal local Documents Directory?

The following code will give me a static list of files in my directory - but I was looking for a more dynamic way so that I could use `NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification`.

Here is my static code to look for files in my documentsDirectory:

```
NSArray* localDocuments = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:
                           [self documentsDirectory] error:nil];

NSArray *onlyPQs = [localDocuments filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.pq'"]];

NSLog(@"local file count: %i", [onlyPQs count]);

for (int i=0; i < [onlyPQs count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"LOCAL:%@", [onlyPQs objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been looking for an answer to this question and, according to the documentation ([Searching iCloud and the Desktop](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/SearchScope.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001841-CH2-SW3)), it's not possible:

> Unlike the desktop, the iOS application’s sandbox is not searchable
>   using the metadata classes. In order to search your application’s
>   sandbox, you will need to traverse the files within the sandbox file
>   system recursively using the NSFileManager class.

On Mac OS X three additional scopes are defined: `NSMetadataQueryUserHomeScope`, `NSMetadataQueryLocalComputerScope` and `NSMetadataQueryNetworkScope` which can be used to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Conform a class to [`NSFilePresenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilepresenter?language=objc) and use an instance with [`[NSFileCoordinator initWithFilePresenter:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilecoordinator/1416795-initwithfilepresenter?language=objc).

Use the `NSFileCoordinator` instance to perform a coordinated read to a directory URL and your subclass should receive updates via the following callbacks (incomplete list, there are more available):

- `presentedSubitemDidChangeAtURL:`
- `presentedSubitemDidAppearAtURL:`
- `presentedSubitemAtURL:didMoveToURL:`
- `accommodatePresentedSubitemDeletionAtURL:completionHandler:`

Subitems are descendants of the directory that is being read. If the presented directory *itself* is a file package, some extra rules apply. Check out the `NSFilePresenter` docs.

**Edit**: Some NSFilePresenter methods are simply not called due to some bugs on Apple's side. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343823/193011 and https://www.objc.io/issues/10-syncing-data/icloud-document-store/#defective-notifications.

This method requires that the file system changes are made using a `NSFilePresenter`. Changes committed by other means are not picked up.

Answer (score -1):

You can monitor the local documents directory with [kqueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html). Apple has [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html) available (in Objective-C).